# Restrict null data result in mapping in JPA

Tags: json, spring-boot, null, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

Entity 1 PriceListDuration.java

```
package com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonPropertyOrder({"priceListId","statusCode","startDate","endDate","orgId"})


@Entity
@Table(name = "qp_price_lists_all_b_AV")
public class PriceListDuration {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PRICE_LIST_ID") 
    private String priceListId; 

    @Column(name = "status_code")   
    private String statusCode; 

    @Column(name = "start_date")    
    private String startDate;

    @Column(name = "end_Date")  
    private String endDate;

    @Column(name = "org_id")    
    private String orgId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRICE_LIST_ID", referencedColumnName = "PRICE_LIST_ID")
    private PriceListDetail pricelistdetails;

    public PriceListDetail getPricelistdetails() {
        return pricelistdetails;
    }

    public void setPricelistdetails(PriceListDetail pricelistdetails) {
        this.pricelistdetails = pricelistdetails;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRICE_LIST_ID", referencedColumnName = "PRICE_LIST_ID")
    private List<PriceListItem> priceListItems;

    public List<PriceListItem> getPriceListItems() {
        return priceListItems;
    }

    public void setPriceListItems(List<PriceListItem> priceListItems) {
        this.priceListItems = priceListItems;
    }

    public String getPriceListId() {
        return priceListId;
    }

    public void setPriceListId(String priceListId) {
        this.priceListId = priceListId;
    }

    public String getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(String statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public String getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public String getOrgId() {
        return orgId;
    }

    public void setOrgId(String orgId) {
        this.orgId = orgId;
    }
}
```

Entity 2: PriceListItem.java

```
package com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumns;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonPropertyOrder({"pricingUOMCode","lineTypeCode","primaryPricingUOMFlag","priceListId","itemId","priceListItemId"})


@Entity
@Table(name = "QP_PRICE_LIST_ITEMS_AV")
public class PriceListItem implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public PriceListItem() {
        super();
    }

    @Column(name = "price_list_item_id")    
    private String priceListItemId;

    @Column(name = "pricing_uom_code")  
    private String pricingUOMCode; 

    @Column(name = "line_type_code")    
    private String lineTypeCode; 

    @Column(name = "primary_pricing_uom_flag")  
    private String primaryPricingUOMFlag;

    @Column(name = "price_list_id") 
    private String priceListId; 

    @Id
    @Column(name = "item_id")   
    private String itemId;

//  For 1-1 mapping
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "inventory_item_id")
    private ItemDetail itemDetails;

    public ItemDetail getItemDetails() {
        return itemDetails;
    }

    public void setItemDetails(ItemDetail itemDetails) {
        this.itemDetails = itemDetails;
    }

    public String getPricingUOMCode() {
        return pricingUOMCode;
    }

    public void setPricingUOMCode(String pricingUOMCode) {
        this.pricingUOMCode = pricingUOMCode;
    }

    public String getLineTypeCode() {
        return lineTypeCode;
    }

    public void setLineTypeCode(String lineTypeCode) {
        this.lineTypeCode = lineTypeCode;
    }

    public String getPrimaryPricingUOMFlag() {
        return primaryPricingUOMFlag;
    }

    public void setPrimaryPricingUOMFlag(String primaryPricingUOMFlag) {
        this.primaryPricingUOMFlag = primaryPricingUOMFlag;
    }

    public String getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(String itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

}
```

Entity 3: ItemDetail.java

```
package com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
@JsonPropertyOrder({"itemNumber","inventoryItemId","organizationId"})


@Entity
@Table(name = "egp_system_items_b_AV")
public class ItemDetail {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "inventory_item_id") 
    private String inventoryItemId; 

    @Column(name = "item_number")   
    private String itemNumber; 

    @Column(name = "organization_id")   
    private String organizationId;

    public String getItemNumber() {
        return itemNumber;
    }

    public void setItemNumber(String itemNumber) {
        this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
    }

    public String getInventoryItemId() {
        return inventoryItemId;
    }

    public void setInventoryItemId(String inventoryItemId) {
        this.inventoryItemId = inventoryItemId;
    }

    public String getOrganizationId() {
        return organizationId;
    }

    public void setOrganizationId(String organizationId) {
        this.organizationId = organizationId;
    }
}
```

We have three Entity where Entity1 is the owner and E1-E2 has 1-M mapping and E2-E3 has 1-1 Mapping.

```
My Controller:
package com.Pricing.Pricing_App.controller;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
//import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model.PriceListDuration;
import com.Pricing.Pricing_App.repository.PriceListDurationRepository;

@RestController
public class PriceListDurationController {

    @Autowired
    private PriceListDurationRepository priceListDurationRepository;

    @GetMapping(value="/getBypriceListId")
    public List<PriceListDuration> getBypriceListId(@RequestParam("priceListId") String priceListId) {
        return priceListDurationRepository.findBypriceListId(priceListId);
    }

}
```

Here is the JSON ouput

```
[
    {
        "priceListId": "300002009417575",
        "statusCode": "APPROVED",
        "startDate": "1998-12-31 00:00:00",
        "endDate": null,
        "orgId": "300001096431127",
        "pricelistdetails": {
            "priceListId": "300002009417575",
            "name": "COMMERCIAL PRICELIST",
            "description": "COMMERCIAL PRICELIST",
            "language": "US"
        },
        "priceListItems": [
            {
                "pricingUOMCode": "zzx",
                "lineTypeCode": "ORA_BUY",
                "primaryPricingUOMFlag": "Y",
                "itemId": "100000763258696",
                "itemDetails": {
                    "itemNumber": "SAM-SOLO-P2-PT",
                    "inventoryItemId": "100000763258696",
                    "organizationId": "300000245868293"
                }
            },
            {
                "pricingUOMCode": "zzx",
                "lineTypeCode": "ORA_BUY",
                "primaryPricingUOMFlag": "Y",
                "itemId": "100000763259581",
                "itemDetails": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As you can see ItemDetails (from Entity 3) is null.
I want to restrict those priceListItems block which has ItemDetails as null.
findBypriceListId returns me the JSON output as given above.
The output also has "itemDetails": null.
I do not want any block which is null in the result.
The expected JSON should not have

```
   {
        "pricingUOMCode": "zzx",
        "lineTypeCode": "ORA_BUY",
        "primaryPricingUOMFlag": "Y",
        "itemId": "100000763259581",
        "itemDetails": null
    }
```

It seems the current implementation is doing outer join

Comment: what does that mean? restrict ? You mean not persist things where a field is null? do a query for something where they are not null? something else? What have you tried? What doesnt work?

Comment: findBypriceListId returns me the JSON output as given above.
The output also has "itemDetails": null.
I do not want any block which is null in the result.
It seems the current implementation is doing outer join

Answer (score 0):

As the best way is while restricting the data in case of retrieving is not much better approach .Rather than you need to restrict data while saving it to table that if it's not null then only you save the column.

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "inventory_item_id") 
@NotNull
private ItemDetail itemDetails;
```